QGIS Processing SAGA nextgen provider does not find SAGA folder
Windows 11, QGIS version: 3.34.13-Prizren, QGIS Processing SAGA nextgen version: 1.0.0


I work with a network Windows profile. It seems that the plugin tries to run CDM from a UNC path (my Document folder): but it doesn't work.
I added cwd = SagaUtils.sagaPath() to the plugin util.py file and now it works!

Or, perhaps better, something like this:

